# Magento session getSingleton failure

Tags: php, magento, session

I have created a custom Session model that (i think) works, and i have two test actions in my action controller.

The first Action is:

```
public function testAction() {
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('mymodule/session');
    $session->func1('x');
    $var1 = Mage::getSingleton('mymodule/session');
    //Tracing through this function reveals that everything behaves as expected,
    //$session is created, modified and then when $var1 is created, the same 
    //reference is returned and the two references refer to the same object
    //($session === $var1) = true
}
```

The second Action is:

```
public function testresultAction() {
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('mymodule/session');
    var_dump($session);
    //this method does not appear to work, and upon tracing through the 
    //getSingleton it is in fact creating a new session object, NOT returning 
    //the one that already existed.
}
```

My session class looks like this:

```
class Mystuff_Mymodule_Model_Session extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract {
public function __construct() {
    $namespace = 'Mystuff_Mymodule';

    $this->init ( $namespace );
    Mage::dispatchEvent ( 'mymodule_session_init', array (
            'mymodule_session' => $this 
    ) );

    $this->setData('history', [] );
    $this->setIndex ( - 1 );
}
    public function func1($historyElement){
        $history = $this->getData( 'history' );
        array_unshift ( $history, $historyElement);
        while ( count ( $history ) > 10 ) {
            array_pop ( $history );
        }
        $this->setData ('history', $history);
        $this->setIndex(-1);
    }
}
```

I have also modified the testresultAction at other points to just `var_dump($_SESSION)` and that seems to have the data in it when i do

SO, Why, when i call my `testAction()` and it creates a singleton and edits data, on concurrent calls to `testresultAction()` is there none of the modified data present, and why does it not get the previously instantiated singleton?

Comment: show us your session class

Comment: @Bixi why should it matter? the only method in there that gets called is already shown?

Comment: Your session class is extending class `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract` I hope, agree with Bixi, we need more of your code to really see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons exist for an execution scope (as you figured out). Session model instances however can store & retrieve data from session storage, meaning that while you don't have access to the same model instance, you do have persistent storage of instance properties.

Therefore, in one execution scope, you could:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$session->setFoo(array('bar'));
//$session->_data['foo'] = array(0=>'bar')
//aka $_SESSION['core'][0]['bar']
```

And then in the next execution scope:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
var_dump($session->getFoo()); //array (size=1){ 0 => string 'bar' (length=3) }
```

I think you are not seeing `$history` because every time you initialize your session model you are overwriting it with

```
$this->setData('history', [] );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. As PHP is stateless, data not put to session only exists during the request-response lifecycle. With `getSingleton` you are simply fetching an  instantiated object if it has been spawned yet.

Answer (score 0):

For those who end up having issues with singletons later

**Magento singletons persist only during the life of the page**

They depend on the *registry* pattern which does **not** persist through several pages.

as for why my data was lost, that would be because since it was creating a NEW singleton(because it was a different action, and thus a different page) it was re-initializing the array to empty

I was not able to find any documentation to verify the lifetime of singletons/registry so if anyone finds that please comment/edit it under here, for completeness